# Some subitems in Sitecore are not published when parent item is being published

Tags: sitecore

I have really strange behavior for me. I would appreciate any help with finding out a solution or just giving an advice how to find out it.

I have such structure of sitecore items:

[image]

Here are several cases:

1. - change "Link1" and "Banner";
   - publish parent item "test 2" with all subitems;
   - Results: "Banner" is changed, "Link1" IS NOT changed

2.

- change "Link1" and "Banner";
- publish parent item "Content" with all subitems;
- Results: "Banner" is changed, "Link1" IS changed too

Does anubody have an idea why shis happens? Why "Link 1" was not published at the first case?

Comment: Please go through this troubleshooting guide: http://blog.martinmiles.net/post/item-not-published-troubleshooting very likely you will find what you are missing here.

Comment: Which version of Sitecore? I've been noticing some weirdness but haven't had time to investigate fully. I found after unchecking "Publish Related Items" in Sitecore 8 the items correctly published, but as I say, haven't had time to investigate, replicate or raise a support ticket yet.

Comment: go on web db and check exactly what you have under test2 item (check for deleted items), you should use a republish on test1 item to fix you problem with deleted items. That's my only idea right now.

Comment: Do you have a workflow in place ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i was able to fix this issue using EventHandler for publish:end - launched a publich programatically if publish item has a type of an item "test 2"

web.config:

```
<event name="publish:end">
    <handler type="YourProject.Infostructure.EventHandlers, YourProject.Infostructure" method="OnPublishEnd" />
</event>
```

EventHandler:

```
public void OnPublishEnd(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        Publisher publisher = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as Publisher;

        if (publisher != null && publisher.Options.Mode == PublishMode.SingleItem && publisher.Options.RootItem.TemplateID == IMicrositeLandingPageConstants.TemplateId &&
            publisher.Options.Deep)
        {
            var item =
                publisher.Options.RootItem.Children.FirstOrDefault(
                    i => i.TemplateID == IContentFolderConstants.TemplateId);

            if (item != null)
            {

                //PUBLISH

                PublishOptions publishOptions =
                    new PublishOptions(item.Database,
                                      Database.GetDatabase("web"),
                                      Sitecore.Publishing.PublishMode.SingleItem,
                                      item.Language,
                                      System.DateTime.Now);  // Create a publisher with the publishoptions
                Publisher publisher2 = new Publisher(publishOptions);

                // Choose where to publish from
                publisher2.Options.RootItem = item;
                // Publish children as well
                publisher2.Options.Deep = true;

                publisher2.Publish();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug. Or at the very least, the symptoms you describe matches exactly what we experienced here.

Unfortunately, Sitecore has not officially published a KB article for the fix. You need to open a Sitecore Support ticket. For reference, the hotfix # is 436732.